# Fixed width HTML table with only one adapting column

Tags: html, html-table

How can I make a HTML two column table where the first column only takes the width it needs but the second fill up to the fixed total table width? So that changing the second column contents does not rebalance the space between the first and second column without assigning a fixed width to the first column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
td:first-child + td { width: 100%; }
```

in CSS. This works on modern browsers. Old versions of IE (up to IE 6) don’t understand the “advanced” selectors used here; for them, you could use

```
<col><col width="100%">
```

in HTML (it does no harm on modern browsers), after the `<table>` tag and before the table rows.

The concept “the width it needs” is somewhat ambiguous if a cell contains spaces or may otherwise be split on two or more lines. A cell with “foo bar” needs more space if “foo” and “bar” are to stay on the same line. By default, browsers may split them. You can prevent this in CSS by saying

```
td:first-child { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Comment: This is fine. The both together look realy nice for 'short keys, long values' style lists. I didn't know the '+' selector before.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
style="width: 100%"
```

To the table cell you want to expand.

Comment: Ok, and is there any solution without modifiyng the table column itself? Like CSS or <col ...> Tag magic...

Comment: Something like '<col style="white-space:nowrap;">        <col style="width: 100%;">' sounds cool unfortenately the nowrap is not working on Chrome browser.

Comment: white-space: nowrap works in Chrome. Perhaps just not on the COL tag. Apply it to the TD

Comment: I thought COL can take any options to be applied to the whole column of td's. A small pity it isn't, would be quite useful. To apply it to the TD, I have to bloat the HTML with class name attribute on every TD.

Comment: Oh, just seen Jukka's answer that contains a CSS solution without class name attributes.